# Why is BluetoothSocket ConnectAsync blocking the UI thread?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I have a simple method I wish to call using await. It looks like this:

```
private async Task<bool> Connect()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    IAsyncResult result = _socket.ConnectAsync();
    var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), true);

    return success;
}
```

I call the method like this (from within an async method):

```
bool cnnSuccess = await Connect();
```

But when the method is called, it is still blocking the UI thread (xamarin.forms project).

I tried adding an await to the ConnectAsync call:

> IAsyncResult result = await _socket.ConnectAsync()

But this produces a compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type void to System.IAsyncResult

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: because you do not `await` the method call : `var result = await _socket.ConnectAsync();`

Comment: What type is that socket exactly?

Comment: @Fildor - it's a BluetoothSocket

Comment: Since `_socket.ConnectAsync` returns a `Task` or void it likely has an event or callback to to indicate when the connection is complete. Read the docs.

Comment: @JSteward It returns `IAsyncResult`, as can be seen from the code snippet.

Comment: @Servy missed that part. In that case `WaitOne` is blocking the calling thread, as someone already commented.

Comment: @JSteward I did, but then thought I was wrong because I found this: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.ConnectAsync()/ but now I am not sure it is the correct one ...

Comment: @Servy - so how can I make that line run async?

Comment: @lepton Read the duplicate.

Comment: @Sevy - I did, but I don't understand how to use Task.Factory.FromAsync with the WaitOne call. Can you show an example of how to use it with WaitOne?

Comment: @Sevy - I don't believe there's enough information in the post you linked to to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `await` with the `ConnectAsync` method call and it should not block the caller like:

```
private async Task<bool> Connect()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    var result = await _socket.ConnectAsync();

    //......... your code here 
}
```

I am not sure what is the return type of `ConnectAsync` here, so you can use `result` to get the needed thing and return back from method.

Comment: This produces a compiler error: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable.

Comment: then looks like `ConnectAsync` returns `Task` not `Task<TResult>`